# CSS - setting icon as a background to input not working

Tags: css

I have a search input field, which has a backround set up like this:

```
background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
```

But, I would like to replace the image for an icon. I am using and have tried to do it like this:

```
input[type=search]:before {
  font-family: 'Ionicons';
  content: '\f2f5';
  color: red;
}
```

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx6s1pua/2/).
But, icon is not visible, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can't use `:before` or `:after`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field) on `<input>` on every browser!

But you can use a solution using a container for the `<input>`:

```css
div span {
  margin-left:-20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <input type="text"/>
  <span class="ion-search"></span>
</div>
```

You can also use a `<label>` surrounding the `<input>` for more accessability:

```css
label[for="search"]:after {
  font-family: 'Ionicons';
  content: '\f2f5';
  color: red;
  margin-left:-20px;
}
label[for="search1"] span {
  margin-left:-20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="search">
  <input id="search" name="search" type="text"/>
</label>

<!-- or -->

<label for="search1">
  <input id="search1" name="search1" type="text"/>
  <span class="ion-search"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: It's worth saying that psudeo elements might work on input elements on some browsers but it is wrong to use it.

Answer (score 2):

`:before` and `:after` can be used on "container" elements only.  An `input` is not a container, because it cannot "contain" other elements.

Wrap the input in a span, and apply the `:before` styles to it:

```
<span class="container"><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></span>

.container:before {
  font-family: 'Ionicons';
  content: '\f2f5';
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/prv6pzLn/2)